# Trying to remove a list of images from a frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to learn som Python and I stumbled over this problem.

I made a small app for dice rolling. It almost works, only problem is that when I roll multiple times it add dices to the list. The old dices should be removed first. I only want one set of dices to show each time.

If youre interested in the entire thing
https://github.com/worblood/vmDice

```
def update_gui():
    for i in range(len(dice)):
        a, b, c = dice[i]
        print(c)

        if "BLACK CRITICAL" in c: #2
            tkimage2= ImageTk.PhotoImage(BlackCriticalSuccess)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage2)
            diceText3.image = tkimage2
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "BLACK SUCCESS" in c: #3
            tkimage3= ImageTk.PhotoImage(BlackSuccess)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage3)
            diceText3.image = tkimage3
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "BLACK FAILURE" in c:#4
            tkimage4= ImageTk.PhotoImage(BlackFailure)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage4)
            diceText3.image = tkimage4
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "RED SUCCESS" in c:#5
            tkimage5= ImageTk.PhotoImage(RedSuccess)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage5)
            diceText3.image = tkimage5
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "RED CRITICAL FAILURE" in c: #6
            tkimage6= ImageTk.PhotoImage(RedCriticalFailure)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage6)
            diceText3.image = tkimage6
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "RED FAILURE" in c: #7
            tkimage7= ImageTk.PhotoImage(RedFailure)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage7)
            diceText3.image = tkimage7
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')
        elif "RED CRITICAL SUCCESS" in c: #8
            tkimage8= ImageTk.PhotoImage(RedCriticalSuccess)
            diceText3 = tk.Label(frame2, image=tkimage8)
            diceText3.image = tkimage8
            diceText3.pack(anchor='c')

# slette gamle bilder fra listen og oppdatere med nye

for widgets in frame2.winfo_children():
    widgets.destroy()
frame2.after(10, update_gui)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple problem of handling the list that contains current dice rolls.
What you want to do is every time you roll the dice again, start by emptying the dice list.

Here is the corrected code.

```
dice = []

def roll_dice():
    global dice
    dice = []
    diceBlackAmount = int(black_amount_entry.get()) # Hente verdien fra input-feltet for antall svarte terninger
    diceRedAmount = int(red_amount_entry.get()) # Hente verdien fra input-feltet for antall røde terninger
```

Comment: Use `dice.clear()`, then you don't need the line `global dice`.

Comment: Yeah true that is an alternative

Comment: Thank you! This was a simple problem I should have overlooked, but then again I never touched Python. This was most helpful and I will continiue my journey into Python.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, good luck out there !